# How to tell rails to use non-default ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, environment-variables

I need two different versions of ruby on a server. The packaged ruby for the packaged puppet to work, and a compiled ruby for a rails web app to work. So basically I want the default ruby to be the ruby from the package, and for rails to use the compiled ruby (in `/usr/local/bin/` and `/usr/local/lib/` )

I've found references to setting the RUBYPATH and RUBYLIB environment variables, but I'm confused as to where to set them. In `.bashrc`, `.profile`, in the apache config somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One trick would be to munge the PATH to include the one you want first.  That is likely a hack though.

If you are using Rails 2.x (which I assume you are) you can specifically run things with a path there, such as:

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby script/server
```

(for development mode for example.)

If you are using something like Phusion Passenger, which I personally recommend, I think it can be set globally for the web server config.  I am not certain if you can do it per-virtual-host using Passenger, but it doesn't sound like you need that.

Comment: +1   RUBYPATH and RUBYLIB are the wrong approach.  The web server needs to know which ruby to use.  RubyEE will actually build mod_rails (Passenger) for you, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but incase anyone else is having this problem just install RVM (http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/)  You can literally switch versions of ruby that the system uses like this (at the command line):

```
rvm 1.9.2
ruby -v  (will display ruby 1.9.2)

rvm 1.8.7 
ruby -v (will display ruby 1.8.7)
```

Simple, no problems!

B